# C# Array of references to Variables and or Form objects

Tags: c#, arrays, reference, func

What I am trying to do is to have an array of references to variables. By which I mean the equivalent to a C array of pointers to ints (for example).

Example: (!!not real code!!)

```
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
int c = 6;
List<ref int> tmp = new List<ref int>();

tmp.Add(ref a);
tmp.Add(ref b);
tmp.Add(ref c);

tmp[0] = 16;
tmp[1] = 3;
tmp[2] = 1000;

Console.Writeline(tmp[0] + " " + a); // 16 16
Console.Writeline(tmp[1] + " " + b); // 3 3
Console.Writeline(tmp[2] + " " + c); // 1000 1000
```

The specifics of my case: I have a list of strings that will correspond to the keys in a dictionary. What I think I want to have is a list of Tuples where Type1 is a reference to either an int or string, and Type2 is a reference to an Textbox.

I will be iterating through this list, using the string to get the value from the dictionary (and doing stuff with that data) then storing the results of that into Type1. And eventually I will be taking the data from those Type1 variable references and copying their data to the corresponding Type2 Textbox.

That's the gist of what I think I want to do. If someone thinks that my approach is overly complicated, I will say that I need to keep the Textboxes as they are sadly, so I can't just make an array and iterate through it. And it would be perferable to keep the Type1 variables seperate too, though not quite as necessary.

Now, from reading around, I thought Func<> looked like it was the closest thing to being useful for what I want, so I tried to use the following (with Type1, as an object because it needs to handle both ints and strings)

```
List<Tuple<string, Func<object>, Func<object>>>
```

but I was unsure how to use that to get references to the variables.

Comment: "If someone thinks that my approach is overly complicated, I will say that I need to keep the Textboxes as they are sadly, so I can't just make an array and iterate through it." - What does this mean?

Comment: you can use pointers in this case, use unsafe keyword for method and set project unsafe to allow pointers in c#, also you can encapsulate the value in a class and in C# each class is of reference type

Comment: @Ahmedsafan: While I disagree with the advisability of what you suggest, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: not sure if I have understood your question well but you can use generics check [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . Func delegates are not really necessary until one is doing async or delay progamming model

Comment: OK, anyway I was trying to give a solution for the technical problem regardless of it's usage.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad: "Func delegates are not really necessary until one is doing async or delay progamming model" What makes you say that?

Comment: @Ahmedsafan: Understood, but comments are not intended for answers. If you have what you feel like is an answer or solution (even if it's partial), it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @AdamRobinson it means if I could turn the Textboxes into an array of boxes, then I wouldnt need to reference them individually, and I could just assign the values in a for loop already.

Comment: @DanielCardin: Why is it that you can't put them into an array or collection? That would not require any change to the way they are created or placed on the form.

Comment: @AdamRobinson i might have not covered all scenarios. But I didn't find the need in this scenario. please correct me if otherwise.

Comment: I never said my approach was correct, I said it was what "I think I want" because i wasn't sure. Though, the proposed solutions seem to compliment how I was doing it, rather than replacing what I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're *specifically* asking for isn't possible; what would be more appropriate (and has the convenience of actually working!) would be to design a class structure around what you're trying to do.

For instance, something like this:

```
public class MyObject // Name it appropriately
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public TextBox TextBox { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your code, you can do something akin to this...

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = ...
List<MyObject> objects = ...

foreach(var item in objects)
{
    item.Value = values[item.Key];

    // process your data

    item.TextBox = item.Value.ToString();
}
```

Obviously, this is just a rough design and the class here serves as little more than a data transfer container. You could make the class "smarter" by, for example, using the setter for the `Value` property to set the value of the `TextBox` automatically. But this should hopefully give you the general idea of how something like this would be done in an OO fashion.

**EDIT** Here's how your example would look.

```
MyObject a = new MyObject() { Value = 4 };
MyObject b = new MyObject() { Value = 5 };
MyObject c = new MyObject() { Value = 6 };
List<MyObject> tmp = new List<MyObject>();

tmp.Add(a);
tmp.Add(b);
tmp.Add(c);

tmp[0].Value = 16;
tmp[1].Value = 3;
tmp[2].Value = 1000;

Console.Writeline(tmp[0].Value.ToString() + " " + a.Value.ToString()); // 16 16
Console.Writeline(tmp[1].Value.ToString() + " " + b.Value.ToString()); // 3 3
Console.Writeline(tmp[2].Value.ToString() + " " + c.Value.ToString()); // 1000 1000
```

Comment: If when I create a MyObject, and set the textbox equal to an existing Texbox on the form, then set the textbox.Text property to something, and that updates whatever was on the form, then this is exactly what I want. If not, I dont see how this would help

Comment: @DanielCardin: Yes, it will. As a `TextBox` is a class (and thus a reference type), then changing a property or any other instance-specific information will be visible anywhere in the program that has access to this instance. In other words, it will do what you want. You might find [this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) interesting. While it's specifically targeted at parameter passing, the information in there is true for all variables.

Comment: and the same would apply to Value just because its in this class?

Comment: I don't know if I just did it wrong, but I tried this out, and it correctly sets the texbox.text like I want it to, but it doesnt seem to change what I input for Value. Meaning with something like new MyObject("test", existingInt, existingTextbox);, it will change existingTextbox, but printing out existingInt will not be what I changed Value to.

Comment: +1 If you only need to worry about changing properties of reference types, I would use this approach.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: This approach works no differently for value types.

Comment: @DanielCardin: The idea is to use the wrapper *instead of* your local variables.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Ah well, I just don't understand. Can you show how your approach would work for my first example where the local int variable `x` is changed by the wrapper? The whole point that I'm going on about is being able to use the wrapper to change a local variable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: As I said in the comments to your answer, strictly speaking *you aren't changing a local variable*. While it appears that way in the code (and functions largely the same, with a few caveats), what it's doing in reality is essentially what I'm doing here. The OP here appears (no offense intended) to be a relative beginner to C#, and making blanket statements like saying the wrapper changes the local variable and introducing the complexity of closures in lambda-defined anonymous delegates when a simple wrapper class would work seems ill-advised.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Fair enough. :)

Comment: @AdamRobinson My point was that I wanted to be able to have named variables that correspond to these things. I suppose it's not impossible to work around, but it makes it less easy to view my data. The point of this structure (from how I wanted it) was to just map the string to the value to the textbox and serve as a conversion . I currently have all these Values in a structure that would make it much easier to access individual entries since each one would have a name and be a property of the class

Comment: @DanielCardin: You can; you simply name the instance of `MyClass` (please call it something more appropriate, though!). See my example. Also, by structure, do you mean `class` or `struct`?

Comment: it's already renamed ;) well right now, I have a class that is just every string/int that I'm keeping track of, where each one is a property. I suppose to keep it with individual variables, I could just put this list in there, and change all the int/strings to instances of MyObject.    EDIT: except that in that class, I couldnt reference my textboxes, unless I add an add method to the class

Answer (score 1):

You can't store references using C#. You can only use the `ref` keyword when calling a method.

You *can* use pointers, but you can only do that with a `fixed` expression and within an `unsafe` context.

It is possible to fake this kind of thing using delegates, but I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for. I'm also fairly sure that you really need to redesign your approach, but nevertheless, here's an example of how you can fake it...

Firstly, write a "value wrapper" class like so:

```
public class ValueWrapper<T>
{
    readonly Func<T>   get;
    readonly Action<T> set;

    public ValueWrapper(Func<T> get, Action<T> set)
    {
        this.get = get;
        this.set = set;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return get();
        }

        set
        {
            set(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use that to change values:

```
void run()
{
    int x = 0;

    var intWrapper = new ValueWrapper<int>(() => x, value => x = value);

    test(intWrapper);

    Console.WriteLine(x);  // Prints 42, which shows that x was changed.

    TextBox textBox = new TextBox {Text = ""};

    var stringWrapper = new ValueWrapper<string>(() => textBox.Text, value => textBox.Text = value);

    test(stringWrapper);

    Console.WriteLine(textBox.Text); // Prints "Changed".
}

static void test(ValueWrapper<int> wrapper)
{
    wrapper.Value = 42;
}

static void test(ValueWrapper<string> wrapper)
{
    wrapper.Value = "Changed";
}
```

You can also create a wrapper in one method and pass it to a different method which uses the wrapper to change a property in the original wrapped object, like so:

```
void run()
{
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox {Text = ""};

    var wrapper = test1(textBox);
    test2(wrapper);
    Console.WriteLine(textBox.Text); // Prints "Changed"
}

void test2(ValueWrapper<string> wrapper)
{
    wrapper.Value = "Changed";
}

ValueWrapper<string> test1(TextBox textBox)
{
    return new ValueWrapper<string>(() => textBox.Text, value => textBox.Text = value);
}
```

Warning: This does lead to some fairly head-scratching code, for example:

```
void run()
{
    var intWrapper = test();
    intWrapper.Value = 42;
    Console.WriteLine(intWrapper.Value); // Works, but where is the value? It can't be the x inside test()!
}

ValueWrapper<int> test()
{
    int x = 0;
    var intWrapper = new ValueWrapper<int>(() => x, value => x = value);
    return intWrapper;
}
```

So we returned a `ValueWrapper` from `test()` which is apparently wrapping a local variable from inside test(). And then we can apparently change the value and print it out...

This isn't really what's happening, of course, but it can be quite confusing!

Comment: +1, though I'm curious why the `get` and `set` delegates (rather than just storing the value in an instance variable)

Comment: @AdamRobinson Because I specifically wanted to change the original value, i.e. the value of `x` on the stack in the `test()` method. Note how the value of `x` actually changes when we call the `test()` method, which makes it *appear* as if a reference to `x` has somehow been used inside `test()`. The magic of captured variables. :)

Comment: I'm aware of what closures can do, but considering it's actually (in reality) doing the very same thing (creating a class to house the local variable, then replacing every access of the local variable after the closure with an access of the property on an instance of that class) but without the overhead of delegate invocation, I don't really see the advantage. There is, in fact, no magic :)

Comment: @AdamRobinson I mean, if you look at the line `Console.WriteLine(x);` it is using `x` directly, *not* the value wrapper. And you can see that `x` has been changed. I'm specifically *not* "replacing every access with an access of the property" (by which I think you mean using the wrapper instead of the original value). The changes made by the wrapper are visible to the code that is using the original value, that's the important point.

Comment: In your code, yes, but not in reality. Take a look at the available documentation on closures and capturing variables in anonymous delegates. These features are entirely syntactic sugar; they are not *actually* expanding the scope or visibility of an instance variable outside of the declaring function (as that's impossible). Or, better yet, look at the IL. You will find that the IL does exactly as I describe.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Hmm I don't really get what you're saying. But consider my second example where the `test1()` method returns a value wrapper, and I pass it to `test2()` which  uses it to change the `Text` property of the original `TextBox` object. That's what I mean.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the concept of closures is a feature of the C# *language*, not of the .NET runtime. In reality, a local variable is never *and can never* be exposed outside the confines of the function that declares it. "Outside" even includes anonymous delegates that are declared within the function that contains the local. When you close over a local variable, it is promoted to an instance variable on an anonymous class, and in the compiled code all references to the local variable that take place after its closed over are  references to the local instance of that anonymous class.

Comment: As a result, what you end up with using the approach you have above is essentially identical to the simple wrapper approach I took in my answer, but you have the added overhead of using *two* wrapper classes and invoking simple get and set operations using delegates. Closures are an awesome tool and they definitely have their place, but it's important to know what is actually happening when you use language features like this.

Comment: @AdamRobinson I'm still not certain how you could use your approach to change a *value* type `x` like in my first example, and then observe the changed value by inspecting `x` rather than anything else.. Doesn't your approach only work with reference types? (I was trying to address the OP's mention of using `ints`.) In any case, I'm certain this isn't what the OP should do - they should redesign!

Comment: No. It would be no different, as the wrapper type is still a reference type regardless of the value that it holds.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pointers in this case, use unsafe keyword for method and set project unsafe to allow pointers in c#, also you can encapsulate the value in a class and in C# each class is of reference type

Answer (score 0):

i used this and works perfect:

exp.

```
public int value1 = 3;
public int value2 = 4;
public int value3 = 5;

public void Method1()
{
    int[] values = { value1, value2, value3};
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Form objects like Labels also can do this.